# Select columns in matrix corresponding to rows

Tags: r, matrix, covariance

So I have a large covariance matrix. I want to pick certain rows, and then have it select the correct corresponding column.
For example:

```
data(data)
data

lng   lat     x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7 x8 x9 x10
-97.5 69.5    .5 .8 .9 .1 .5 .3 .2 .4 .6 .2
-101.5 49.5    .5 .8 .9 .1 .5 .3 .2 .4 .6 .2
-98.5 89.5    .5 .8 .9 .1 .5 .3 .2 .4 .6 .2
-97.5 49.5    .5 .8 .9 .1 .5 .3 .2 .4 .6 .2
-107.5 79.5   .5 .8 .9 .1 .5 .3 .2 .4 .6 .2
-92.5 29.5    .5 .8 .9 .1 .5 .3 .2 .4 .6 .2
-97.5 48.5    .5 .8 .9 .1 .5 .3 .2 .4 .6 .2
-91.5 19.5    .5 .8 .9 .1 .5 .3 .2 .4 .6 .2
-97.5 37.5    .5 .8 .9 .1 .5 .3 .2 .4 .6 .2
-80.5 39.5    .5 .8 .9 .1 .5 .3 .2 .4 .6 .2
```

This is a covariance matrix so x1 = lng -97.5 and lat 69.5 and so on.
Right now I have

```
section_data <- subset(data, -97.5 <= lng & lng <= -80.5 & 35.5 <= lat & lat <= 49.5)
```

So that's rows 4,7,8,9,10.
That gives me

```
 lng   lat     x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7 x8 x9 x10
-97.5 49.5    .5 .8 .9 .1 .5 .3 .2 .4 .6 .2
-97.5 48.5    .5 .8 .9 .1 .5 .3 .2 .4 .6 .2
-91.5 19.5    .5 .8 .9 .1 .5 .3 .2 .4 .6 .2
-97.5 37.5    .5 .8 .9 .1 .5 .3 .2 .4 .6 .2
-80.5 39.5    .5 .8 .9 .1 .5 .3 .2 .4 .6 .2
```

but it doesn't take away the columns that correspond to that. I **want** it to give me rows 4,7,8,9,10 but only with columns 4,7,8,9,10.

```
 lng   lat     x4 x7 x8 x9 x10
-97.5 49.5    .1 .2 .4 .6 .2
-97.5 48.5    .1 .2 .4 .6 .2
-91.5 19.5    .1 .2 .4 .6 .2
-97.5 37.5    .1 .2 .4 .6 .2
-80.5 39.5    .1 .2 .4 .6 .2
```

I searched and searched but I couldn't find any answers to help me with my question.
I would appreciate any help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
Indices = with(data, 
              which(-97.5 <= lng & lng <= -80.5 & 35.5 <= lat & lat <= 49.5))
Rows = Indices
Columns = Indices + 2
Columns = c(1:2, Columns)
section_data <- data[Rows,Columns]
```

Comment: you may want to add `1:2` to `Columns`.

Comment: You could also obtain the last line with just: `section_data <- data[Indices,Indices+2]`.